# passing arrays to taxonomy metabox

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

Good evening... I would like to pass array values as options to an array key (options).

This is what I would like to achieve:

```
        array(
            'name'    => 'Select',
            'id'      => 'select',
            'type'    => 'select',
            'options' => array(  // Array of value => label pairs for radio options
                'value1' => 'Label 1',
                'value2' => 'Label 2'
            ),
        ),
```

Can't seem to pass a variable as options values. Example

```
$myarray = array('value1' => 'Label 1', 'value2' => 'Label 2')

array(
    'name'    => 'Select',
    'id'      => 'select',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => $myarray
),
```

The plugin I am working with is Taxonomy Meta from http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/taxonomy-meta-script-for-wordpress. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use proper PHP syntax and it will work just fine. Try this

```
<?php
$myarray = array('value1' => 'Label 1', 'value2' => 'Label 2');

$arr = array(
    'name'    => 'Select',
    'id'      => 'select',
    'type'    => 'select',
    'options' => $myarray
);

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response... Actually, its a nested arrays, I only had to paste a section instead of copying the whole code. Kindly check out this page: https://github.com/rilwis/taxonomy-meta/blob/master/demo.php under the //Select comment.

Comment: Yes of course that would work as well, but that was not what you had in your questions. Still now you know 2 ways to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for it. I wasn't doing anything wrong except that I created the variable outside the function that created the array.

All I did was to create the variable inside the function that created the array and it worked. Thanks @RiggsFolly.